# iOS FSCalendar delegate not working when calendar is in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

i created a cell which contains FSCalendar. I'm registering my cell to table view in my controller but delegate is not working.

My cell is like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: FSCalendar!
@IBOutlet weak var nextMonthButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var previousMonthButton: UIButton!
```

In my view controller, i connected tableview's delegate and datasource, registered my cell. However, cell's calendar's delegate methods are not working. What should i do?

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not setup the delegate and datasource for the calendarView property. You either have to initialize it under tableViewCell’s **awakeFromNib()** method or on your controller’s **tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)** method where you are drawing the cell.

```
cell.calendarView.delegate = self
cell.calendarView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: I forgot to thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding. :)